# Initializing sizes of nested vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

If I wanted to create a vector of vectors of the same size, how can I do this with one initialization line?

e.g.

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv(5)` would default initialize 5 vectors, but how to initialize those 5 vectors to a size?

Comment: @lllllllllll `auto &i` or you're modifying a copy. But it isn't a one-line initialization either way.

Comment: why not to use C++ array then? It's better to use resize on the next line then  the solutions below (`...vv(5, std::vector<int>(5, 0));`). I can instead of int values use int arrays of size 1 based on the `OP` logic.

Answer (score 6):

Like following :

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vv(5, std::vector<int>(5, 0)); // Initialize with 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the two-argument constructor:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vv(5, std::vector<int>(5));
```

Not very efficient, though.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @Chara, If you're looking for efficient code, a 2D vector is a bad start. If all of the inner vectors must have the same length, you can use a matrix class. If you know the length beforehand, `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas allow very complex initialisation in one line, if one line is really what you want.

This statement creates a vector of 5 vectors, each of which contains the sequence, 0-4, 5-9, 10-14...

```
auto vv = [] { 
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    result.reserve(5);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), 
                    5, 
                    [&i]{ 
                      auto v = std::vector<int>();
                      v.reserve(5);
                      std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 5, [&i]{ return i++; });
                     return v;
                    });
    return result;
  }();
```

If you want it on one line, simply remove all the spaces:

(no, I don't really advise this...)

```
auto vv = [] { int i = 0; std::vector<std::vector<int>> result; result.reserve(5); std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), 5, [&i]{ auto v = std::vector<int>(); v.reserve(5); std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 5, [&i]{ return i++; }); return v; }); return result; }();
```

Comment: FYI, `std::iota` does what your `std::generate_n` call is doing.

Comment: @chris so it does - at least for the inner loop. you'd still have to track the value for the outer one though, right?

Comment: Yup, it's either that or use an iterator that goes through both dimensions (which doesn't exist in the standard). Alternatively,  an `array_view` treating it as a single dimension and then iterating through that.